# Bootstrap 4 separate cards in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having issues with separating card's in bootstrap 4 in mobile view.  I tried using `bottom-margin` it works, however, the jumbotron is not the same size as the cards anymore in desktop view. I would like the jumbotron to have the same width as the three cards.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.nav-toggle').click(function() {
  var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');
  var toggle_switch = $(this);
  $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function() {
   if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
    toggle_switch.html('View All');
   } else {
    toggle_switch.html('Close');
   }
  });
 });
});
```

```css
.jumbotron {
 background-color: white;
}

.card-deck{
    bottom-margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <section class="selection-portfolio" id="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
   <h1 class="text-center">TEST</h1>
   <h2 class="text-center">Test</h2>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item card-deck">
     <div class="card h-100">
      <img alt="team_husky_logo" class="card-img-top" src="">
      <div class="card-body">
       <h4 class="card-title">
       <p class="card-text"></p><a class="btn btn-outline-primary text-center" href=""><i class="far fa-image"></i></a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item card-deck">
     <div class="card h-100">
      <img alt="ads" class="card-img-top" src="ads">
      <div class="card-body">
       <h4 class="card-title">
       <p class="card-text">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken.</p>
       <p>.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item card-deck">
     <div class="card h-100">
      <img alt="ClickTrack" class="card-img-top" src="">
      <div class="card-body">
       <h4 class="card-title">
       <p class="card-text">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
     <br>
     <h2 class="text-center">All Projects</h2>
     <div class="jumbotron">
      But I must explain to you how all this mistaken
      <hr>
      <div id="collapse" style="display:none">
       "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
      </div><a class="nav-toggle hover-regular" href="#collapse">View All</a>
     </div>


  </div>
 </section><!--portfolio end-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't a normal **card-deck** what you want? 
The mixture of BS-grid markup and `.card-deck` in your code is weird.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.nav-toggle').click(function() {
    var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');
    var toggle_switch = $(this);
    $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function() {
      if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
        toggle_switch.html('View All');
      } else {
        toggle_switch.html('Close');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.jumbotron {
  background-color: white;
}

.card-deck {}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section class="selection-portfolio" id="portfolio">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">TEST</h1>
    <h2 class="text-center">Test</h2>



    <div class="card-deck">


      <div class="card">
        <img alt="team_husky_logo" class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/400/300?image=20">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">
            <p class="card-text"></p>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary text-center" href=""><i class="far fa-image"></i> Test</a>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="card">
        <img alt="ads" class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/400/300?image=21">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <p class="card-text">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken.</p>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="card">
        <img alt="ClickTrack" class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/400/300?image=22">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <p class="card-text">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <h2 class="text-center">All Projects</h2>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      But I must explain to you how all this mistaken
      <hr>
      <div id="collapse" style="display:none">
        "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human
        happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves
        or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical
        exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
      </div><a class="nav-toggle hover-regular" href="#collapse">View All</a>
    </div>


  </div>
</section>
<!--portfolio end-->
```